# How to properly simulate hemmed cloth objects

Tags: cloth-simulation

I’m trying to model a children’s bookcase which has two stiff fabric drawers on the bottom (which I’m treating as rigid), and 4-part sling hung from a diagonal array of 5 wooden poles. Each of the poles is threaded through a sewn channel about 5 inches in circumference. The sling is hemmed on each end.

I modeled the pre-simulation in cross-section as 4 “J”s coming out the bottom of 5 circles. While my initial instinct was to make all this “solidified” (2 vertices thick), reading on the cloth sim lead me to revise my model to 1 vertex thick along its length, and only doubled for the 3 columns of faces on the end. I have the faces 1/4” squared... the two layers are only connected at the outside edge and the inner edge of the SECOND column (so the last double face is free on the edge. Lengthwise, the first and last channel also have a trailing row of faces dangling from the “channel” circle.

When I try to simulate this, the mesh just goes crazy and explodes off the poles. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't appear to have adequate reputation score to attach a non-image file, so here is the `.blend` file from pasteall.org:
[childrens_bookcase.blend](https://pasteall.org/blend/fe1cb59cf2b24db9b1854033dfdae0a8)

Comment: an image would help a lot. A .blend file would be perfect to help you.

Comment: Yes. I intended to add a .blend file and a couple images when I get back to my computer.

Comment: I believe I got to the bottom of MOST of my issues: The biggest issue was the collision distance was way to big for the scale I was working at. Also my surface normals, which I thought might be consistent, being extruded from a single mesh edge, were all over the place. I made sure all my normals were consistent. I’m trying to work out the last kinks before posting an answer.